# adMob Interstitial Ad loaded verification

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, admob, interstitial

Here is my code I am using to determine if adMob interstitial is ready to display.

```
func presentInterstitial() {
    if showAds == true {
        if let isReady = interstitial?.isReady {
            println("isReady is true")
            interstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self)
        } else {
            println("ad not ready")
        }
    }
}
```

It always comes back true even when I cut network and hence no ads can possibly be loaded.

Comment: Use the delegate methods provided by the AdMob Framework. https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/ad-events

Comment: @Daniel Storm: I am using the delegates.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was the resultant Bool value being optional. I had to separately unwrap it to make it work.